# Add hyperlink to apache.poi.xslf autoshape

Tags: java, apache-poi, slideshow, powerpoint

I am creating a Powerpoint presentaion(s) with apache poi xslf library. I need to create a Autoshape and when click on the autoshape it should go to the specific slide.

I can do this by adding text to the autoshape and creating a hyperlink like below.

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
XSLFSlide slide1 = ppt.createSlide();
XSLFSlide slide2 = ppt.createSlide();
XSLFSlide slide3 = ppt.createSlide();
XSLFAutoShape sh1 = slide1.createAutoShape();
sh1.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 50, 100, 50));
XSLFTextRun r2 = sh1.addNewTextParagraph().addNewTextRun();
XSLFHyperlink link2 = r2.createHyperlink();
r2.setText("Go to Slide 3");
link2.setAddress(slide3);
```

But the problem is when I create an Auto shape like this, it actually link the text and not the shape. Also when I open it from Powerpoint it show the hyperlink in blue color underlined text which I don't want.

In Powerpoint, you can right click on an Autoshape and then link it to a different slide. This links the auto shape and if you click anywhere in the autoshape it takes you to the linked slide, also it does not show the text in blue underlined format. This is the effect I am trying to achieve.

I need to use org.apache.poi.xslf library. I found a way to do a similar thing in org.apache.poi.hslf library. But I can't use it since I need the XSLF library for some other features.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: No idea how to do this w/ the library you're using but you're creating a hyperlink on a text run within a shape rather than on the shape itself, which is why you're getting the results you see.

Comment: Yes. There is no method to add the Hyperlink to the shape. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can link a AutoShape to a special slide, therefore you must use some own logic:

```
CTShapeNonVisual shapeProperty = XmlObjectReaderUtil.getElementValue(sh1.getXmlObject(), CTShapeNonVisual.class, XmlObjectReaderUtil.NEW_CT_SHAPE_NON_VISUAL);
CTNonVisualDrawingProps cNvPr = shapeProperty.getCNvPr();
CTHyperlink hlinkClick = cNvPr.getHlinkClick();
if (hlinkClick == null) {
  hlinkClick = cNvPr.addNewHlinkClick();
}
PackageRelationship rel = autoShape.getSheet()
                   .getPackagePart()
                   .addRelationship(slide3.getPackagePart().getPartName(),
                            TargetMode.INTERNAL,
                            XSLFRelation.SLIDE.getRelation());
hlinkClick.setId(rel.getId());
hlinkClick.setAction("ppaction://hlinksldjump");

//Helper class
public final class XmlObjectReaderUtil {

  public static final String NEW_CT_SHAPE_NON_VISUAL = "declare namespace main='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main' main:nvSpPr";

  private XmlObjectReaderUtil() {
    //Static-Service Class
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T extends XmlObject> T getElementValue(XmlObject xmlObject, Class<T> clazz, String xquery) {
    XmlObject[] rs = xmlObject.selectPath(xquery);
        if (rs.length == 0) {
          return null;
        }
        return (clazz.isInstance(rs[0])) ? (T)rs[0] : null;
  }
}
```